# Retrieve the returned value of an execution

Tags: lua

I am implementing a Lua REPL. I use readline to read a command and then do:

```c
luaL_dostring(L, myinput);
```

How can I retrieve the value returned by the execution if there is any? For example, if `myinput` contains a function call `add(1, 1)`, how I can retrieve 2 here?

I tried reading the stack with `lua_tointeger` but the stack is empty (`lua_gettop` returns 0).

I would like to avoid modifying `myinput` to do something like `ans = add(1, 1)` and then reading the global if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myinput` is just `add(1, 1)`, that's a function call statement, so the return value(s) of `add` will be discarded. You can't recover them afterwards.

It is not possible to circumvent this without modifying `myinput`.

You can test this in the Lua 5.1 and 5.2 REPLs: They have the same issue. If you enter an expression, that's a syntax error. If you enter a function call, that's just a statement, so you get no return values out of it.

However, all chunks in Lua are effectively functions, so you can just `return` any values you want to. In the Lua 5.1 / 5.2 REPLs, you could write `return 1 + 1`, and it would print `2`. Because this is slightly cumbersome, they offer `=` at the start of the input as syntactic sugar for `return` .

What you can do - and what the Lua 5.3 / 5.4 REPLs do - is first try prepending `return`  and appending `;` (see [the source](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/e288c5a91883793d14ed9e9d93464f6ee0b08915/lua.c#L574)), and if that works, they evaluate the chunk and print the return values. That's what makes expressions work in the REPL. It's a bit of a hack, but it works well.

(Also, what is `lua_dostring`? It doesn't appear in the reference manual or the PUC sources.)

---

> I am implementing a Lua interpreter.

Nitpick: It sounds like you're implementing a Lua *REPL* (read-eval-print-loop, an interface to an interpreter) rather than a Lua *interpreter* (the software that *interprets* the Lua code).

---

> Also, what happens if the code surrounded by return ; do a side effect AND fail...

The side effect (say, a `print`) will happen as normal, there is no "isolation" here. The "failure" will make the REPL print a stacktrace; no "values" will be printed. You can easily test this yourself using `print` and `error`.

Comment: Sorry the function is called luaL_dostring: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#luaL_dostring. Changed "interpreters" to "REPL" in my question. Thanks!

Comment: If you add this link to the code I'll accept you answer: https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/e288c5a91883793d14ed9e9d93464f6ee0b08915/lua.c#L574

Comment: Also, what happens if the code surrounded by `return ;` do a side effect AND fail...